# Formal arguments for a multidimensional array

Tags: c

What is the suggested way to define function arguments for a nested array? For example, here are three possibilities:

```
int process(int (*coord)[2], size_t size)
{
   ...
}
```

```
int process(int coord[4][2], size_t size)
{
   ...
}
```

```
int process(int coord[][2], size_t size)
{
   ...
}
```

Are there all identical, or do any of these function arguments differ from the others?

Comment: This is tricky. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Comment: They are all identical, and the "suggested way" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @user3386109 I see, so `coord[4]` decays to `(coord*)`. In other words the outermost array goes to a pointer?

Comment: An array decays to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function.

Comment: Specifically, I'm pretty sure the 4 is silently ignored in all types of `C`; it's just a pointer. It's more so the human readers can follow.

Comment: @user3386109 so would `int coord[1][2][3][4]` go to `int (coord*)[2][3][4]` ?

Comment: The `*` is misplaced, but the idea is correct.

Comment: @user3386109 cool! what IDE is that?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> suggested way to define function arguments for a nested array?

All identical, follow your group's coding standard. [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084926/formal-arguments-for-a-multidimensional-array/66085330#comment116838582_66084926) [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084926/formal-arguments-for-a-multidimensional-array/66085330#comment116838840_66084926)

---

Consider a 4th option that aligns with a new C2X [new principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features): "the size of an array appears before the array", if indeed that parameter `size` is meant in this way.

```
int process(size_t size, int coord[size][2]) {
```

Comment: @user3386109 I doubt C2X will require `VLA` as a local object declaration, yet requiring as allowed in the pointed to type (or as a function parameter)  is not so bad and quite useful as a pointer too: e.g. `int (*ptr)[a][b];`  I guess we will find out when C2X comes out.